# DIsplaying SSRS reports in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I have a series of reports served by SSRS.  They are great and the users like them.

That being the case, upper management wants to throw a wrench in the works and serve the reports from the Sharepoint server.

Is there a realtively painless way to let users access the reports from sharepoint?  How would somebody go about doing such a thing?  Or do I just need to bite the bullet and try to stop the madness?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of SSRS or Sharepoint you're using, but there have traditionally been both a Report Viewer and a Report Explorer web part shipped with Sharepoint in the RSWebParts.CAB file (at least since SQL Server 2005 SP2 I think). You can start there, but if you wanted quick and low-tech you could put in an IFRAME web part and point it to the Reports folder on your SSRS Server. Since you're using Sharepoint, that's also making the assumption that you're using Windows Authentication, so that wouldn't be an issue there.

Here's a link that might be of some use:
[Viewing Reports with SharePoint 2.0 Web Parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159772.aspx)

Comment: I would stick with the report viewer/explorer web part

Answer (score 5):

The most painless is going to be to run SSRS in Native mode, which it sounds like you're doing already, then install the SSRS web parts on your WSS/MOSS server.

You will have to manage security and report source control using some other methods besides sharepoint, however you don't have to deal with installing WSS/MOSS on your SSRS box and adding it to your SharePoint farm.

The more painful option is to run SSRS in Integrated mode. This allows you to use all the SharePoint document management stuff for your reports and share the same security setup however, the server configuration can be lengthy and difficult to setup.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677365.aspx

Hope this helps!

Ben